# extSD card does not work after adb push to /mtn/extSdCard

Tags: adb, external-sd

After I run `adb push cm-11-20141115-SNAPSHOT-M12-i9300.zip /mnt/extSdCard` the command replied me `3949 KB/s (223217798 bytes in 55.194s)`.

After that my micro SD-card is not detected neither by device nor by my laptop?